# Simple Server-Client outside local network?

Tags: c#, client, server

i moved to C# from Java and now i'm a bit confused...

In Java i wrote a Server-Client program that can do many things between the Server and the Client.
Now i'm trying to write the same program in C#. I've just started but i'm already stuck.

I tried to use a `TcpListener` for the Server and a `TcpClient` for the Client, everything worked fine, they were able to connect and send strings to each other inside my local network.

But i read online that `TcpListener` and `TcpClient` cannot connect from outside the local network, in fact i tried to connect them using my global ip (2.23X.XXX.XX) and i got an error.

Then i made some research online but i didn't find nothing about how to make a Server-Client program in C# wich works from outside the local network...

So i was wondering if anyone can explain me how to do this. Maybe provide a simple example wich shows how to setup the server to listen and the client to connect.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english, it's not my mother tongue.

---

**EDIT:**

In Java i used `ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);` and in a while loop `Socket connection = server.accept();`.

And on the client side `Socket client = new Socket("2.23X.XXX.XX", port);`.

I don't have a NAT, just the modem with UPnP.

Comment: Puzzled... I really don't think that there's a difference between Java and C# here, as soon as there are firewalls or NAT between server and client the network infrastructure will be configured to let this traffic pass.  What makes you think that there is any difference between Java and C#'s behavior?  How did you solve this problem in Java?

Comment: Small sample Java code (or at least briefe description) that *worked* in the same environment would help explaining difference of behavior you see... There should be nothing C# specific in a way TCP routing works.

Comment: In java i just used Sockets and they worked fine... I don't have a NAT or anything, just the modem. The program thrown an exception saying "ip is not valid in its context".

Comment: If you actually don't use nat or or router or anything, the output of `ipconfig` should be your public IP address (2.23X.XXX.XX).  Is that the case?  If it is, check, using `netstat -an` if there's something already listening on the port you try to listen on.

Comment: Nothing is already listening non that port. But something strange is going on, the IPv4 Address from ipconfig is "25.136.247.230"... That's my Hamachi IP... but Hamachi is not running and i also closed the tunneling process from task manager...

Comment: Ok i unistalled Hamachi and now ipconfig shows 192.168.1.3, wich is my ip on the router, a DSL-2740b  (sorry if i told you i haven't got a router but i didn't know). The router default ip is 192.168.1.1.